.htaccess IfModule without matching ifmodule, but all IfModule are equal ...?
on my .htaccess file
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    
    RewriteEngine On
    
    
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?host\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.host.com/$1 [R,L]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php

</IfModule>

# php BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit


but the error on error.log
[core:alert] [pid 20265] [client ::1:56116] /var/www/html/system/dashboard/.htaccess: </IfModule> without matching <IfModule> section
once I tried to remove the .htaccess code It gave me
[core:alert] [pid 20264] [client ::1:41726] /var/www/html/system/dashboard/.htaccess: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbf', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
I tried to allow all over ride but it already allowed

'\xef\xbb\xbf' is the UTF8 encoded version of the unicode ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE U+FEFF. It is often used as a Byte Order Mark at the beginning of unicode text files. That suggests that you edited those files with some fancy tool, but not a normal text editor. And now you have unprintable control characters in them which might very well break their structure. Try recreating those configuration files by means of a simple ascii editor or storing them in ASCII mode if your editor has such thing.

thank you ... thats right I've solved this by making the file encoding format in UTF8 instead of UTF8-with BOM and it worked
